# How to print numpy array with 3 decimal places?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I print numpy array with 3 decimal places? I tried `array.round(3)` but it keeps printing like this `6.000e-01`. Is there an option to make it print like this: `6.000`?

I got one solution as `print ("%0.3f" % arr)`, but I want a global solution i.e. not doing that every time I want to check the array contents.

Comment: Your first problem is that `6.000e-01 != 6.000`. `6.000e-01 == 0.6`.

Comment: I don't think you can convince numpy to print `6.000e-01` as `6.000` ;-) maybe as `0.600`...

Comment: try `np.set_printoptions(precision=3)`

Comment: try ```np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)``` when you have very small value.

Comment: @behzad.nouri thank you for providing a solution, without any smart-a** comment like above yours. This could be turned into an answer, I guess.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
 np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: "{0:0.3f}".format(x)})
```

This will set numpy to use this lambda function for formatting every float it prints out.

other types you can define formatting for (from the docstring of the function)

```
    - 'bool'
    - 'int'
    - 'timedelta' : a `numpy.timedelta64`
    - 'datetime' : a `numpy.datetime64`
    - 'float'
    - 'longfloat' : 128-bit floats
    - 'complexfloat'
    - 'longcomplexfloat' : composed of two 128-bit floats
    - 'numpy_str' : types `numpy.string_` and `numpy.unicode_`
    - 'str' : all other strings

Other keys that can be used to set a group of types at once are::

    - 'all' : sets all types
    - 'int_kind' : sets 'int'
    - 'float_kind' : sets 'float' and 'longfloat'
    - 'complex_kind' : sets 'complexfloat' and 'longcomplexfloat'
    - 'str_kind' : sets 'str' and 'numpystr'
```

Comment: sorry I removed the acceptance. np.set_printoptions() doesn't accept a formatter!

Comment: If it won't accept a formatter, you might be running a old version of numpy. I'm not sure when this feature was added. But it is documented, so it is indeed supported: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html

Comment: Worth noting you don't need the lambda: `np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float':           "{0:0.3f}".format})` will work, since format is already a function.

Comment: Still works in 1.23.1. Note there's also a context-manager for this: [numpy.printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html#numpy.printoptions).

Comment: The context manager can be used as:
with np.printoptions(precision=2):
   print(an_array)

Answer (score 49):

Actually what you need is `np.set_printoptions(precision=3)`. There are a lot of [helpful other parameters there](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

For example:

```
np.random.seed(seed=0)
a = np.random.rand(3, 2)
print a
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print a
```

will show you the following:

```
[[ 0.5488135   0.71518937]
 [ 0.60276338  0.54488318]
 [ 0.4236548   0.64589411]]
[[ 0.549  0.715]
 [ 0.603  0.545]
 [ 0.424  0.646]]
```

Comment: Your example works. But I don't know why in my jupyter notebook, it still shows something like ```[  5.000e-02   2.139e-01   1.028e+00 ...,   1.804e+03   1.805e+03
   1.806e+03]```

Comment: In the end, this works: ```np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)```, since small value could be suppressed. Refer to the doc [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

Answer (score 34):

An easier solution is to use numpy around.

```
>>> randomArray = np.random.rand(2,2)
>>> print(randomArray)
array([[ 0.07562557,  0.01266064],
   [ 0.02759759,  0.05495717]])
>>> print(np.around(randomArray,3))
[[ 0.076  0.013]
 [ 0.028  0.055]]
```

Comment: This does not prevent numpy from using scientific notation.