# Sequentially add elements in numpy array into new array

Tags: python

I'm curious if there is a built in function to transform an array of values into a cumulative array of values.

Example:

```
input = np.asarray([0.000,1.500,2.100,5.000])
```

**into**

> [0.000,1.500,3.600,8.600]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in-built [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) from NumPy to get the cumulative sum of your array `inputt` as

```
inputt = np.asarray([0.000,1.500,2.100,5.000])
print (np.cumsum(inputt)) 

# [0.  1.5 3.6 8.6]
```

I renamed your array because `input` is already an in-built function in python to get the user input from the keyboard

Comment: out of curiosity do you know how to truncate it at 100?

Comment: @jparanich: 8.6 and 8.6000 are equivalent. But still you can control the number of digits after decimal while printing them. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222818/how-to-printing-numpy-array-with-3-decimal-places)

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. I meant truncate the cumulative rolling numbers at 100 so the sum does not exceed 100.